# Magento: how to debug varienForm?

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

I'm trying create own extention based on importexport extention.
The structure is very similar to importexport module.

File /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/importexport/import/form/before.phtml has **postToFrame** method. **formElem.action** url is correct on "Check data" pressing. But after  "Check data" pressed only *loading-mask* has showed and nothing happend.

I tried to debug it using firebug. There are not any js answers.
Then I set alerts before and after this._submit(); They both showed.

How to debug it then? How to get any anwers from server?

**PS1:**
For example

`varienForm.prototype.ifrElemName = 'someID';`

And I didn't set or did mistake in the theme template file:

```
<h4 id="some_ID"><?php echo $this->__('Validation Results'); ?></h4>
```

If it was jQuery then there would be used follow checking:

> alert($('someID').length);

or for getting result post:

```
$.post('/post.php', postdata, function(data){
     console.log(data);
});
```

How I would know about my bug here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the exact same things in PrototypeJS

```
alert($('someID'))
```

will still alert for you. This will tell you if the element with that ID exists on the page when the javascript fires. If the alert comes back with `undefined` or `null` then the element doesn't exist yet.

for a AJAX Post

```
new Ajax.Request('/post.php',{'method':'post','parameters':postdata,'onSuccess':function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

`data` is a ajax respone object you can get the text of the response in `data.responseText` or if your response has the `Content-Type: application/json` set it will automatically be evaluated as JSON and be returned in `data.responseJSON`.

Comment: It's just example how simple to debug in jQuery. In magento a little bit difficult. For example you cannot get any info does $(this.formId).submit() submitted or not. If you do following code in jquery $(this.formId).submit(); alert("!"); then you dont get an alert. But if you do the same in prototype (or in magento js lib, I don't know does it depend on) you got it...